# Inflate 2.xml files with TextViews to show correctly in Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, layout-inflater

My goal is to show url links (normal and mirror links) in TextViews which are part of **two** different .xml files which are being inflated and then shown **below** each other in a RecyclerView.
The two .xml files are identical, except for the TextView IDs (text and mir), below 1 example:

mirror_text_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:clickable="true">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mir"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Below code of the DownloadAdapter works so far but the **mirror links are always shown in the TextView (id: text) part of the .xml (download_text_item)**, they should show in the tv (id: mir) part of mirror_text_item.xml which is located below the download_text_item.xml.

DownloadAdapter:

```
public class DownloadAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DownloadAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    String[] items;
    Fragment fragment;

    public DownloadAdapter(Fragment fragment, String[] items) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
        this.items = items;
    }

    class MirrorViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
        private TextView textView;
        private View itemView;

        public MirrorViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mir);
            this.itemView = itemView;
        }
    }

    class DownloadViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
        private TextView textView;
        private View itemView;

        public DownloadViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            this.itemView = itemView;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public DownloadAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View a, v = null;

        if (Utils.downloadVis == 0) {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.download_text_item, parent, false);
            return new DownloadViewHolder(v);
        }
        else {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.mirror_text_item, parent, false);
            return new MirrorViewHolder(v);
        }
    }


    public String getSelection(int position) {
        return items[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DownloadAdapter.ViewHolder viewholder, final int position) {
        final String item = Utils.unescapeJavaString(Html.fromHtml(getSelection(position)).toString());

        if(viewholder instanceof DownloadViewHolder){
            DownloadViewHolder holder = (DownloadViewHolder) viewholder;
            holder.textView.setText(item);

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Utils.openUri(fragment, item);
                }
            });
        } else {
            MirrorViewHolder holder = (MirrorViewHolder) viewholder;
            holder.textView.setText("Just a test!");

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Utils.openUri(fragment, item);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.length;
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView text, mir;
        private View itemView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            mir = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mir);
            this.itemView = itemView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the mistake is in the implementation of `getItemViewType`

Comment: Hi Blackbelt, thx for the reply. Could you pls assist what it should look like? This troubles me for some time now.

Comment: I am not sure about your code, but accordingly to what you wrote you should have `return Utils.downloadVis == 0 ? 0 : 1;` instead then just `return 1`. `onCreateViewHolder` should check `viewType` instead of `Utils.downloadVis`

Comment: Utils.downloadVis is an int which is set as soon as a "mirror:" string is found in the fetched content.
1 the mirror string is there 0 not, according to that another TextView with just the Text (Mirrors:) is shown or not.